# Expand dataframe in R with rbind (union)

Tags: r, rbind

I need to scale up a set of files for a proof of concept in my company. Essentially have several 1000row files with around 200 columns each, and I want to rbind them until I reach the desired scale. This might be 1Million rows or more.

The output will be essentially a repetition of data (sounds a bit silly) and I'm aware of that, but i just need to prove something.

I used a while loop in R similar to this:

```
while(nrow(df) < 1000000) {df <- rbind(df,df);}
```

This seems to work but it looks a bit computationally heavy. It might might take like 10-15minutes.

I though of creating a function (below) and use an "apply" family function on the df, but couldn't succeed:

```
scaleup_function <- function(x) 
{ 
  while(nrow(df) < 1000)
  {
    x <- rbind(df, df)
  }

}
```

Is there a quicker and more efficient way of doing it (it doesn't need to be with rbind) ?

Many thanks, 
Joao

Comment: why dont you first check the `dim()` of each data.frame, add them and that might tell us how many `df` to be `rbind()` right. Then just a single step is required and no loop. Just a thought

Comment: Growing an object (and a data.frame in particular) in a loop is just about the slowest operation you can do when programming. That's what you are proving. Alternatives have been discussed here numerous times. Possibly you could do something like `df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1000),][1:1000,]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
df <- matrix(0,nrow=1000,ncol=200)
reps_needed <- ceiling(1000000 / nrow(df))
df_scaled <- df[rep(1:nrow(df),reps_needed),]
```